# Vagrant machine unable to authenticate with my newly created user over ssh

Tags: ruby, ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

My vagrantfile looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

vagrant_home = "/home/vagrant/"
local_share = "#{ENV['HOME']}"

unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
  puts "Vagrant plugin 'vagrant-vbguest' is not installed!"
  puts "Execute: vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest"
end

unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-sshfs")
  puts "Vagrant plugin 'vagrant-sshfs' is not installed!"
  puts "Execute: vagrant plugin install vagrant-sshfs"
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |stage|
    stage.vm.box = "centos/7"
    stage.vm.hostname = "HSS-IAAS-VB"
    stage.vm.box_check_update = true
    stage.vm.network "private_network", :type => 'dhcp'
    stage.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "centos7-dev"
      vb.gui = false
      vb.memory = "1024"
    stage.ssh.keys_only = false
    stage.ssh.username = "#{ENV['USER']}"
    stage.ssh.forward_agent    = true
    stage.ssh.insert_key       = true
    stage.ssh.private_key_path =  "#{ENV['HOME']}/.ssh/id_rsa" , "/home/#{ENV['USER']}/.ssh/id_rsa
    stage.vm.provision :shell, privileged: false do |s|
      ssh_pub_key = File.readlines("#{Dir.home}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub").first.strip
      s.inline = <<-SHELL
        echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> #{ENV['home']}.ssh/authorized_keys
        sudo bash -c \"echo #{ssh_pub_key} >> #{ENV['home']}/.ssh/authorized_keys\"
      SHELL
    end
  end
end
```

My issue is that when I run this vagrantfile, I receive an error that states the following: `default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...` and if I run in debug mode I just see a bunch of timeouts..

All that I am trying to do is rather than create a "vagrant" user, I want to create a user that is the same as the user on the host machine by using `#{ENV['USER']}` and have the user immediately be able to run `vagrant ssh` and if their host user is test.user, then the guest user will be test.user..

`vagrant ssh-config` was:

```
Host default
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User aaron.west
  Port 2200
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/aaron.west/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentityFile /Users/aaron.west/.ssh/id_rsa
  LogLevel FATAL
```

all help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to create a new user on your Vagrant machine.  As per the docs for the [ssh.username](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html#available-settings) setting, it doesn't sound like that setting actually creates a user.  It only helps you to tell Vagrant what user to connect as, if the box was made with a username other than *vagrant*.

You probably need to shell out to `useradd` during provisioning.

Comment: so if I am to understand this correctly... Should I allow the vagrant user to provision the additional users?

Comment: You need to actually **create** that user, unless it already exists on the box you're using to create your machine.  More interesting to me, is why you need a user of a different name ... what special use scenario do you have that means you can't use the `vagrant` user?

Comment: I am trying to set up a dev env for dummies... so I would really like to be able to NFS mount the host home dir to the guest home dir and use the same user.name. basically as seamless as possible :) this would even let them use their own IDEs without having to sync changes with that vagrant box..

Comment: I already have the NFS mount working in such a way that in mounts a user.name (host user.name home dir) dir to the ~vagrant user home dir (~vagrant/user.name)

Comment: That's what the Vagrant shared folder is for, right?

Comment: the vagrant shared dir at '/vagrant' or the one i mounted at '~vagrant/user.name'?

Comment: I guess I'm missing why you need to mount the entire user home directory.  Just the shared folder with the project in it should be sufficient.  Particularly if this is for "dummies" then you might not want them mucking around in the home directory getting lost.

Comment: ahh, that makes sense.. I wouldn't want them to accidentally destroy their host_home dir thinking that they are doing a "clean up" or something :)